# How to Remove duplicated picture in gallery when using android camera?

Tags: android, camera, gallery

I use the Android camera to take a picture in my activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImagePath());
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

When I leave the camera app, the photo is saved in two places:

1. At the path specified by the getImagePath() method (which is correct) ;
2. Into the gallery. I don't whant that.

How can I prevent the photo to be saved into the gallery? And if I can't do it, how can I get the photo path in my onActivityResult() so I can delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` you can delete the gallery file (after copying it to your folder).  Perhaps this would also work for `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` (with `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`).  I use the following code snippet for deleting the gallery file on return from `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
  String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
  Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
  int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  Uri u = data.getData();
  new File(getRealPathFromURI(u)).delete();
  ...
```

Comment: This method doesn't work with an intent Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) because the intent (data, in your case) that is returned in onActivityResult is null !

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the image to the SD card somewhere in your getImagePath() code? If so, the Android Media Scanner is picking it up from that location to display in the gallery. You can create an empty file named .nomedia in the directory where your images are saved to have the Media Scanner ignore all the media files in that folder.

Comment: No, the getImagePath() only returns an Uri. I wasn't aware of the .nomedia file, could be useful for the future. It won't solve my problem, though.

Comment: Where are you saving your images files to?